# Which is more efficient. if(a-b >0) or if (a > b)

Tags: algorithm, performance

This might be a simple question.

I want to know which of the 2 statements will take less time to get executed.

```
if ( a - b > 0 ) or if ( a > b )
```

In the 1st case, the difference has to be computed and then it has to be compared with 0, while in the 2nd case, a and b are compared directly.

Thanks.

Comment: As always, these little differences mean nothing on today's computers. And if it MIGHT matter, it depends on your compiler. So use a profiler and find out yourself in your own situation.

Comment: This sort of micro-optimisation has already cost you more time in posting the question than you are ever likely to recover in improved performance.

Comment: What language? Which compiler? Invoked with what options? The two are not necessarily equivalent; `a - b` can overflow.

Comment: If the intent is to test whether `a` is greater than `b` then do `if (a > b)`. If the other was faster then your compiler should do that transformation for you.

Answer (score 2):

As Keith Thompson points out, the two are *not* the same. If `a` and `b` are unsigned, for example, `a-b` is always non-negative, making the statement equivalent to `if(a != b)`.

Anyway, I did an unrealistic test:

```
int main() {
    volatile int a, b;

    if(a-b>=0)
        printf("a");

    if(a>b)
        printf("b");

    return  0;
}
```

Compile it with `-O3`. Here's the disassembly:

```
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp3:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp4:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    subl    -8(%rbp), %eax
    testl   %eax, %eax
    jle LBB0_2
## BB#1:
    movl    $97, %edi
    callq   _putchar
LBB0_2:
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    cmpl    -8(%rbp), %eax
    jle LBB0_4
## BB#3:
    movl    $98, %edi
    callq   _putchar
LBB0_4:
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    addq    $16, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

At `-O3`, `a-b>0` is still using one extra instruction.

Even if you compile it with an ARM compiler, there's an extra instruction:

```
    push    {lr}
    sub sp, sp, #12
    ldr r2, [sp, #0]
    ldr r3, [sp, #4]
    subs    r3, r2, r3
    cmp r3, #0
    ble .L2
    movs    r0, #97
    bl  putchar(PLT)
.L2:
    ldr r2, [sp, #0]
    ldr r3, [sp, #4]
    cmp r2, r3
    ble .L3
    movs    r0, #98
    bl  putchar(PLT)
.L3:
    movs    r0, #0
    add sp, sp, #12
    pop {pc}
```

Note that (1) `volatile` is unrealistic unless you are dealing with e.g. hardware registers or thread-shared memory, and (2) that the difference in practice is not even measurable.

Because the two have different semantics in some cases, **write what is correct**. Worry about optimization later!

Answer (score 1):

If you really like to know, in C, suppose we have `test.c`:

```
int main()
{
  int a = 1000, b = 2000;
  if (a > b) {
    int c = 2;
  }
  if (a - b > 0) {
    int c = 3;
  }
}
```

Compile with `gcc -S -O0 test.c`, we got `test.s`:

```
.file   "test.c"
.text
.globl  main
.type   main, @function
main:

.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    $1000, -16(%rbp)
    movl    $2000, -12(%rbp)
    movl    -16(%rbp), %eax
    cmpl    -12(%rbp), %eax
    jle .L2
    movl    $2, -8(%rbp)
.L2:
    movl    -12(%rbp), %eax
    movl    -16(%rbp), %edx
    subl    %eax, %edx
    movl    %edx, %eax
    testl   %eax, %eax
    jle .L4
    movl    $3, -4(%rbp)
.L4:
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Please see the above

```
    movl    $1000, -16(%rbp)
    movl    $2000, -12(%rbp)
    movl    -16(%rbp), %eax
    cmpl    -12(%rbp), %eax
    jle .L2
    movl    $2, -8(%rbp)
```

and

```
    movl    -12(%rbp), %eax
    movl    -16(%rbp), %edx
    subl    %eax, %edx
    movl    %edx, %eax
    testl   %eax, %eax
    jle .L4
    movl    $3, -4(%rbp)
```

`a - b > 0` needs one more step.

**Note**

1. *The above are compiled on `Ubuntu 14.04` with `gcc 4.8`, with optimization turned off (`-O0`)*
2. As pointed out by @Blastfurnace, *With `-O2` or `-O3`, the assembly code are no longer readable.  You need to profile to get a idea.  But I believe they will be optimized to the same code.*
3. Who cares

Comment: Since the question is about performance why would you turn off optimizations?

Comment: @Blastfurnace With `-O2` or `-O3`, the above simple example optimized to nothing.  Actually in my opinion, `-O2` or `-O3`, the code would be no difference.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: To try to prevent optimizing everything away you could read `a` and `b` from stdin and print `c`. Your third point is correct though.

Answer (score 1):

If doing the subtract and testing the sign had the same result as the comparison and ran faster, the processor designers would have mapped the integer compare instruction to a subtract and test.

I think you can assume the compare is at least as fast as subtract and test, as well as having the really major advantage of being clearer.

Answer (score 0):

for readability, I always go with `a > b`